# Pushing Only Recent History to a New Git Repo

Tags: git

I have a legacy repository that has been corrupted through some misdirection of LFS and files that are no longer accessible. The result is that it requires access to files that no longer exist to push to a new repository or major surgery on the history that seems too difficult/risky that this time. I would like to attempt to create a new repository and push only recent history to avoid the old and bad commits. Say, all commits since a certain date or from a certain commit. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just delete everything before the first "good" commit?

One easy way:

```
git rebase -i --root
```

You are shown a list of all commits in reverse order from the start, e.g.

```
pick aa48e9c start
pick e10b625 middle
pick 6691860 finished up
```

Let's say we want to get rid of "start" and "middle" but keep "finished up". So just delete those two lines and save.

```
pick 6691860 finished up
```

An artificial empty first commit will be created, but the bad commits will be gone. There might be some conflicts to work out but it shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Also, worth noting that this will only edit the history on one particular branch, which is fine as long as that's all you need to push to the new remote repository. If you need to preserve any other branches or tags, a more sophisticated rewrite will probably be necessary. It also doesn't technically _delete the old commits_, it _recreates the newer ones_; a subtle distinction, but one worth keeping in mind, to understand how it will interact with other actions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try `git rebase --onto <sha1> <sha2> <sha3>`(see [this link](http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20120928/git-how-to-copy-a-range-of-commits-from-one-branch-to-another/)) functionality where

- sha1: The new base
- sha2: The parent of the first commit that will be copied (sha2 will not be copied itself)
- sha3: The last, most recent commit which will be copied

So all in all something like this:

1. Setup a new local repository named `newRepo`

```
mkdir newRepo
cd newRepo
git init
```

2. Create an initial commit in `newRepo` just to initialize master branch

```
touch temp_file_for_initial_commit
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit of new corruption-free repository"
```

3. Get all the history from the `oldRepo`

```
git add origin "/path/to/oldRepo" # notice it could just be a path to the local repo
git fetch origin
```

4. Use `git rebase --onto` to copy old range of valid commits to new repo

```
git rebase --onto master <sha of parent of first commit> <sha of latest commit>
```

5. Make a branch for new history

```
git checkout -b latest-history-on-new-repo
```

6. Clean up reference to old repo

```
git remote remove origin
```